# face becomes twisted after trying to bevel into a cylinder shape

Tags: bevel

[image]

i'm trying to create a cylinder shape on the end of this curve, but after selecting 2 edges and beveling them, it becomes twisted like this

Comment: Which two edges? Why are you using an old version?

Comment: If you've set the curve to Twisted Mode > Z-Up it may explain

Comment: to me, it looks like you beveled it too heavy: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2lrI.gif

Comment: I've seen your first (deleted) question which was about modeling high heels. Is this tutorial [Speed Modeling Heels in Blender 2.79](https://youtu.be/rspLH2td97I) the reason why you use the old Blender 2.79 version? For beginners, it's hard to get familiar with the GUI and there are major changes in the GUI between 2.79 and 2.8. But I still would recommend updating the Blender version if you can.

Comment: I'm using an old version of blender because the heels i'm trying to make are for the sims 4 and sims 4 studio only accepts a certain version of blender....       also, blunder is right, I beveled it too heavy. I did a smaller bevel and this fixed it. thank you.